# JSONObject to JSONObject class cast exception

Tags: java, arrays, json

I am trying to parse my JSONObject to get my JSON Array's data.

But the problem is JSONParser is a class in org.json.simple.JSONParser and the JSONObject is in org.json.JSONObject.

I cannot find any parser in org.json to avoid class **cast exception!**

Do we have any other way to get this stuff sorted...?

Or am i going in a completely wrong direction?
Please suggest

My JSON looks like :

```
{
 "dataIntents": [
 {
  "intent": "muster.policy.daily",
  "expr": "Am I supposed to register my attendance daily?"
 },
 {
  "intent": "leave.probation",
  "expr": "An employee is eligible for how many leaves in 1st year ??"
 },
 {
  "intent": " leave.resigned ",
  "expr": "Are resigned employees eligible for pro rata leave credit"
 },
 {
  "intent": " muster.deadline.submission ",
  "expr": "By when should I get my pending leave/Emuster applications 
 approved?"
  }
 ]
}
```

My main class:

```
public class DLMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {

try {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        Object obj = 
        parser.parse(newFileReader("/home/cmss/Downloads/data.json"));
        org.json.JSONObject dataObject = (org.json.JSONObject)obj;
        System.out.println(dataObject);
        org.json.JSONArray getArray = 
        dataObject.getJSONArray("dataIntents");

        for (int i = 0; i < getArray.length(); i++) {
            org.json.JSONObject objects = getArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String a = objects.getString("expr");
        }
        System.out.println();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
  }
}
```

I want all values of my "expr" key in a JSONObject or String.

Help appreciated in advance :)

Comment: Try using `org.json.simple.JSONObject` and `org.json.simple.JSONArray`

Comment: @SpaceBison if i use org.simple.json.JSONArray then i am getting an error on   dataObject.getJSONArray("dataIntents");

Comment: `org.json.simple.JSONObject` has a different interface than `org.json.JSONObject` since it from a different library. For details, consult the docs: http://alex-public-doc.s3.amazonaws.com/json_simple-1.1/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a POJO for that?

So far your Json is a list of intents, you can have something like:

```
public class Intents {
    private List<Intent> dataIntents;
}
```

and another

```
public class Intent {
    private String intent;
    private String expr;
}
```

(please generate the constructor and getter setter)

And then you can use directly the [ObjectMapper](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) and you avoid all the ugly JSON parsing.

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but i dont want to use a pojo class . I want my program to be light weighted

Comment: Do you weight your code on kilograms of code printed? ;) (is a joke) code is much better when it is understandable, but maybe that is my personal opinion.

Comment: actually i dont want to make it complicated. I just want to use simple JSON Library  instead of making pojo's. This instance is for making a chatbot so needed for that. Thankuou :)